# Text has \n and response has both \n and "real new lines". print() output both as line breaks

Tags: python, string, artificial-intelligence, openai-api

I have some Python function like this:

```
def translate(text):
    while True:
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-4",
            messages=[
                {"role": "system", "content": "You are a translator, you will receive English language sentences from a videogame needing localization. You must respect the punctuation and capitalization. You must maintain \n as is"},
                {"role": "system", "content": "The target language is Spanish"},
                {"role": "user", "content": text}
            ],
            temperature=0
        )
        return response.choices[0].message['content']
```

and for the `text` input parameter I have a string like this (but really longer):

```
text_to_translate = """
Blocks melee and\n ranged units' line of sight.
Sink the unit. Sunken\n units are more vulnerable to enemy attacks.
Teleport the unit through\n this portal to an exit portal.
"""
```

For the response I'm doing:

```
translated_text = translate(text_to_translate)
print(translated_text, flush=True)
```

The problem is, print() is taking \n and (correctly) inserting line breaks on the output like this:

```
Bloquea la línea de visión de
unidades de combate cuerpo a cuerpo y a distancia.
Hunde la unidad. Las unidades
hundidas son más vulnerables a los ataques enemigos.
Teletransporta la unidad a través
de este portal a un portal de salida.
```

How can I make it so \n stay the same but the actual line breaks from the triple-quoted strings are respected?

Comment: There's no difference between `\n` and an actual newline. If you don't want escape sequences to be processed, use a raw string by starting with `r"""`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I'm confused because I thought I had tried that before, but I just went ahead and tried it one more time since it does sound obvious. I must have burned my brain for the day. How can I flag this as an answer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string literal (regardless of the quotes used) is not the same thing as a `str` value. The *literal* contains a `\n` digraph; the `str` value it creates contains U+000a.

```
>>> x = """foo\nbar
...baz"""
>>> len(x)
11  # not 12
>>> x
'foo\nbar\nbaz'  # String representation of a string uses a digraph
>>> print(x)  # U+000a is rendered as a line break and a carriage return
foo
bar
baz
```